# How to center align a group of <a> tags and understand what's going on

Tags: html, css

Trying to center div that contains a group of `<a>` tags, that is contained in a nav in a div as such in code provided. Not sure how to, and also want to understand which selector I use and why for aligning it to the center.

I tried text-align: center; on the div "top-nav-2". I don't want to use flexbox or grid, just basic floats, text-align, etc

```
/* HTML */

<nav class='top-nav'>
     <div class="top-nav-2">
         <a class="weed" href="#">Shitendo</a>
         <a href="#">Pilates-Station: Move</a>
         <a href="#">Micro-Box</a>
         <a href="#">SEGA-Genitalia</a>
         <a href="#">Trash Bin</a>
     </div>
</nav>

/* CSS */
/* Nav bar */

.top-nav{
    display: block !important;
    background-color: #003371;
    height: 51px; 
 }

.top-nav-2 > a{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #addeeb;
    border-left: 10px;
 }
```

Trying to make it look like website https://www.ebgames.com.au/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with the old display: inline-block and text-align: center; way of doing this, although you could use flexbox if you'd prefer.

```css
.top-nav{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #003371;
    height: 51px;
}

.top-nav-2 > a{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #addeeb;
    border-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class='top-nav'>
        <div class="top-nav-2">
            <a class="weed" href="#">Shitendo</a>
            <a href="#">Pilates-Station: Move</a>
            <a href="#">Micro-Box</a>
            <a href="#">SEGA-Genitalia</a>
            <a href="#">Trash Bin</a>
       </div>
</nav>
```

Here's the flexbox version, in case you want to see it:
https://jsfiddle.net/6j2upgz7/

Comment: you've got two `display:inline-block;` in `a` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
.top-nav-2 {
text-align:center;
}
```

Add this styling to your code, if you only want to set the center to top-nav-2

Or you can add text-align:center to the top-nav that you already have